# Pandas: (By groups based on 1 column) How to both forward fill and backward fill a column based on the values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Was looking to do the following by groups of another column (category column), sorted by date.

1. forward fill value in "value" column, if the "value_stage" column has a "start" value in the same row.
2. Then after doing above, backward fill the value in "value" column, if the "value_stage" column has a "end" value in the same row.

Please find an example below.

This is my data

```
pd.DataFrame([['2022-01-01','A','',''],['2022-01-02','A','3','End'],['2022-01-03','A','4','Start'],['2022-01-04','A','',''],['2022-01-05','A','2','Start'],['2022-01-06','A','',''],['2022-01-07','A','',''],
              ['2022-01-01','B','3','End'],['2022-01-02','B','',''],['2022-01-03','B','1','Start'],['2022-01-04','B','',''],['2022-01-05','B','',''],['2022-01-06','B','2','end'],['2022-01-07','B','',''],
             ['2022-01-01','C','',''],['2022-01-02','C','3','End'],['2022-01-03','C','',''],['2022-01-04','C','1','End'],], columns = ['date', 'category', 'value','value_stage'])
```

This is how the output looks like

```
 pd.DataFrame([['2022-01-01','A','3',''],['2022-01-02','A','3','End'],['2022-01-03','A','4','Start'],['2022-01-04','A','4',''],['2022-01-05','A','2','Start'],['2022-01-06','A','2',''],['2022-01-07','A','2',''],
              ['2022-01-01','B','3','End'],['2022-01-02','B','',''],['2022-01-03','B','1','Start'],['2022-01-04','B','1',''],['2022-01-05','B','1',''],['2022-01-06','B','2','end'],['2022-01-07','B','',''],
             ['2022-01-01','C','3','End'],['2022-01-02','C','3','End'],['2022-01-03','C','1','End'],['2022-01-04','C','1','End'],], columns = ['date', 'category', 'value','value_stage'])
```

From the output, category 'A' has the value 4 forward filled on Jan 4, because the Jan 3's "value_stage" =  "start" and also then had backfill for Jan 1 since the Jan 2 "value_stage" = "End". (Same is the case with Jan 6,7, ffill from JAn 5 for category 5)
Category 'B' also has the value 1 forward filled on Jan 4, Jan 5 since Jan 3's "value_stage" =  "start" . Since Category has neither the "start", "end" values in the last columns, nothing was done.

Update - Please note: A category can have multiple "Start" (in case of example A above) and multiple "End" each associated with a different values. (to illustrate this added 3 more days to category A and B at the end : Jan 5 - Jan 7)

Comment: Why does your output dataframe have more rows than your input dataframe?

Comment: @Xukrao updated the input too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method should be able to cope with multiple starts and multiple ends within a category:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['2022-01-01','A','',''],['2022-01-02','A','3','End'],['2022-01-03','A','4','Start'],['2022-01-04','A','',''],['2022-01-05','A','2','Start'],['2022-01-06','A','',''],['2022-01-07','A','',''],
                   ['2022-01-01','B','3','End'],['2022-01-02','B','',''],['2022-01-03','B','1','Start'],['2022-01-04','B','',''],['2022-01-05','B','',''],['2022-01-06','B','2','End'],['2022-01-07','B','',''],
                   ['2022-01-01','C','',''],['2022-01-02','C','3','End'],['2022-01-03','C','',''],['2022-01-04','C','1','End'],], columns = ['date', 'category', 'value','value_stage'])

# Replace empty strings with `nan` (required for the pandas forward-fill and
# backward-fill methods to work)
df[['value', 'value_stage']] = df[['value', 'value_stage']].replace('', np.nan)

def fill(gdf):
    mask_f = gdf['value_stage'].ffill() == 'Start'
    mask_b = gdf['value_stage'].bfill() == 'End'
    gdf.loc[mask_f, 'value'] = gdf.loc[mask_f, 'value'].ffill()
    gdf.loc[mask_b, 'value'] = gdf.loc[mask_b, 'value'].bfill()
    return gdf

# Perform forward and backward fill for each individual category
df = df.groupby('category', group_keys=False).apply(fill)

# Optional: revert any remaining `nan` values back to empty strings
df[['value', 'value_stage']] = df[['value', 'value_stage']].replace(np.nan, '')

print(df)
```

which gives the result:

```
          date category value value_stage
0   2022-01-01        A     3            
1   2022-01-02        A     3         End
2   2022-01-03        A     4       Start
3   2022-01-04        A     4            
4   2022-01-05        A     2       Start
5   2022-01-06        A     2            
6   2022-01-07        A     2            
7   2022-01-01        B     3         End
8   2022-01-02        B                  
9   2022-01-03        B     1       Start
10  2022-01-04        B     1            
11  2022-01-05        B     1            
12  2022-01-06        B     2         End
13  2022-01-07        B                  
14  2022-01-01        C     3            
15  2022-01-02        C     3         End
16  2022-01-03        C     1            
17  2022-01-04        C     1         End
```

Comment: I'd have used the same approach ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
def fill_dataframe(g):
    g = g.replace("", np.nan)
    filtered = g[~g["value_stage"].isna()]

    if len(filtered) == 0:
        return g.fillna("")

    start, end = filtered.index[0], filtered.index[-1]

    # is first value "End"?
    if filtered["value_stage"].iat[0] == "End":
        g.loc[:start, "value"] = g.loc[:start, "value"].fillna(filtered["value"].iat[0])

    # is last value "Start"?
    if filtered["value_stage"].iat[-1] == "Start":
        g.loc[end:, "value"] = g.loc[end:, "value"].fillna(filtered["value"].iat[-1])

    current, state = np.nan, None
    for i, val, stage in zip(
        g.loc[start:end].index,
        g.loc[start:end, "value"],
        g.loc[start:end, "value_stage"],
    ):
        if stage == "Start":
            state, current = stage, val
        elif stage == "End":
            state, current = stage, np.nan

        if state == "Start":
            g.loc[i, "value"] = current

    return g.fillna("")


df = df.groupby("category", group_keys=False).apply(fill_dataframe)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          date category value value_stage
0   2022-01-01        A     3            
1   2022-01-02        A     3         End
2   2022-01-03        A     4       Start
3   2022-01-04        A     4            
4   2022-01-05        A     2       Start
5   2022-01-06        A     2            
6   2022-01-07        A     2            
7   2022-01-01        B     3         End
8   2022-01-02        B                  
9   2022-01-03        B     1       Start
10  2022-01-04        B     1            
11  2022-01-05        B     1            
12  2022-01-06        B     2         End
13  2022-01-07        B                  
14  2022-01-01        C                  
15  2022-01-02        C                  
16  2022-01-03        C                  
17  2022-01-04        C
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works for the example, but often I need to back fill more than the first occurrence of  "End", please see the example of category C, that I updated in question. It has 2 "End"s in it and requires backfilling the values of both , how should I approach this ? Thanks again.